# Accessing the label's text field in asp

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp repeater in my webpage. I am making the infrastructure of a forum site, My question is, the repeater gets the answers to the question from database with ItemDataBound Method. If a file is attached, the download button and the filename labels are visible. I do the check in the ItemDataBound method. But when I click download button, I want to get filename on the label, which belongs to the same repeater with that downlaod button. this.label.text did not help

Thanks for your answers.

This is the Part of ItemDataBound method  that I do the check. I want to see the content of CevapEk label on the exact same repeater so I can generate a download link.

```
string s = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "dosya").ToString();

if (s != "")
{
    CevapEk = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("CevapEk");
    if (CevapEk != null)
    {
        CevapEk.Text = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "dosya").ToString();
        CevapEk.Visible = true;

    }
    Button CevapEkIndir = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("CevapEkIndir");
    if (CevapEk != null)
    {
        CevapEkIndir.Text = "Indir";
        CevapEkIndir.Visible = true;
    }
    HiddenField hdn = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hdnCevapEk");
}
```

And this is the download event method. I need the filename at the start (string dosya)

```
protected void CevapEkIndir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.CevapEk != null)
    {
        string dosya = this.CevapEk.Text;

        string dosya_path = @"\uploadCevap\";

        dosya_path = dosya_path + dosya;
        Response.Clear();

        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + dosya);
        Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(dosya_path));
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected void CevapEkIndir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button CevapEkIndir = ((Button)sender);
    Control container = CevapEkIndir.NamingContainer;
    Label CevapEk = (Label)container.FindControl("CevapEk");

    if (CevapEk != null)
    {
        string dosya = CevapEk.Text;

        string dosya_path = @"\uploadCevap\";

        dosya_path = dosya_path + dosya;
        Response.Clear();

        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + dosya);
        Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(dosya_path));
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will test it as soon as the server is up!